# How to preserve browser console log in Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, microsoft-edge

I have one main page which is calling a popup page. I have written console logs in onbeforeunload event which will be called when I will close the popup window. I want these logs to investigate one issue. The issue is not reproducible when I am debugging the the JS. So I want console logs written at the time of closing the popup window without debugging. But when I am closing the popup window the logs are getting disappeared with the popup window. I have also checked the preserve log checkbox from the **Developer tool> Console> Setting** section. But it didn't solve my issue. I am unable to view any logs even after selecting this option.
Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you should have a preserve logs option in the preferences.. can you find it?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita No, I can't find it. I think preferences is available in Safari browser.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but it works fine, just like [this screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLmuv.gif). If possible, could you describe your issue more clearly?

Comment: No, I don't have right to share the screen recording or code. Have you checked on latest version of MS Edge chromium browser?

Comment: I tested this example on Edge 103.0.1264.44 and I found that Edge was updated to 103.0.1264.49 and it still works fine.